# Assembly NASM writing to reserved space

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

If I reserve some place for my use later on like this:

```
section .bss
LC1:
    RESB    256
```

How can I write characters or numbers there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By enclosing the address in brackets. For example:

```
mov [LC1],eax       ; Store the value of eax at address LC1
mov byte [LC1+8],0  ; Store the 8-bit immediate 0 at address LC1+8
```

Refer to the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html) for further information (in particular section 3.3).